# VSCode - Disable 'This may be converted to an async function' tooltip message

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to disable this specific tooltip message (and the 3 dots that comes with it on the function name) (Image 1)?

**Image 1:**
[image]

Tried this and it's not working:
Set `"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` or `"typescript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` to disable these.

Already tried (unsuccessfully):
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61326
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28825
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37332

Comment: So those settings you pasted into your question: **`"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` & `"typescript.suggestionActions.enabled": false`** work for me when turning that message off, however; The problem that most other people face with this solution to get rid of the suggestion is that there is no way disable this suggestionAction without disabling all suggestionActions. Currently that is where VSCode stands with this issue. And, as you know (which I know you know cuz I read your GitHub Comments, sneaky of me huh? lol :P ), it is Currently is an Issue on GitHub.